# Better structure for database information

Tags: mysql

I have a list of users with information, currently at like 60+ and a list of products that users could have, which contains like 15 products as of right now. Both lists will grow with the users one growing at a greater speed than the products one.

Is it better to add a products field to the users table and just keep the products there or should I make a separate table for products and under each one, add the users that own that product.

Or does it just not even matter.

Comment: "Is it better" - better for what?

Comment: Just general optimization. Following standards. Whatever. I'm just trying to learn more about sql and these are the kinds of questions I wonder about.

Answer (score 0):

One user might have more than one product, so a join table is a good option.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about joins. I can kind of get it from the examples on the php site but could you give a simple example, or point me to a good one?

Comment: Java Persistence/OneToMany --> Example of a OneToMany using a JoinTable database  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_using_a_JoinTable_database

Comment: I recommend you go with this answer